# dotenv: Unhandled Exception: Instance of 'FileNotFoundError'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dotenv

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await dotenv.load(fileName: "./env");
  var documentsDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    
  Hive.init(documentsDirectory.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserDataModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(TaskHiveModelAdapter());
    
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

My file directory:

[image]

Error on build:

```bash
No file or variants found for asset: .env.
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
    
Target debug_android_application failed: Exception: Failed to bundle asset files.
    
    
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I have the `.env` set up in `pubspec.yaml` like so:

```yaml
assets:
  - .env
```

How can Flutter don't find the `.env` file on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The **relative path** might be causing issues, you can try using an **absolute path** to the `.env` file.

```dart
await dotenv.load(fileName: '/full/path/to/your/project/.env');
```

OR

```dart
await dotenv.load(fileName: 'env');
```

2. Do check your `pubspec.yaml` file to ensure that the `.env` file is present in the assets.

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - .env
```

3. Make sure the File Permissions:
   Make sure that you have read access to the `.env` file.

Comment: I updated my question. Can you check it again, please?

Comment: Did you try using absolute path and OR option.

Comment: yes, it threw me the same error I put up there in my question for both outcomes

Comment: Can you please run this command `flutter clean`  OR
`flutter build <platform>` . Platform such as android or ios.

Comment: I get it. The .env file is supposed to be in the root directory, not inside the lib folder as I did. Now it's working perfectly with your suggestion. Thank you so much!